# Xamarin Forms - Background image for half page

Tags: c#, image, xamarin, background

I'm quite new with Xamarin Forms and i'm trying to split the XAML page to have a background image on the top "row" and a white background in the bottom "row".

[image: Check the following example]

The gray background represents the background image i currently have, and it's located in the ContentPage tag. In this case, the white background does not reach the full width of the screen (because it's inside a Grid.Row of the ContentPage) neither the bottom of the screen.
If i just add the background image in the first row of the grid, the page title (Iniciar Sesion) will not have the background image.

I just need to split the whole ContentPage in 2 rows, one with a background image and the other without it.
I really need to do it in the XAML, not in C#.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: create a grid with 2 rows, and place your image in the BG of the first row.  Then add another nested grid to each row to contain your other controls.

Comment: @Jason thanks for the response! If i add the background image to a grid, i will have those white paddings. The only way i could get rid of the paddings is by adding the background image to the ContentPage.
ContentPage -> Image = No paddings, but no half/half background.
ContentPage -> Grid -> Image = Half/Half background but paddings.

Comment: you should be able to change the padding on the grid so it fills the entire page

Comment: I think i'm not getting you. I cannot use negative paddings so the grid overflows the ContentPage. Do you have any example? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can easily achieve your request with a Relative Layout (click [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/relative-layout/) to learn for Relative Layout in Xamarin Documentation) :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ContentPage 
    xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
    x:Class="YourNamesapce.YourPage">
    <RelativeLayout>
        <Image
            RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
            Property=Width,Factor=1}"
            RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent,
            Property=Height,Factor=0.5}" 
            Source="icon.png"
            Aspect="AspectFill"/>

   <Grid
        RelativeLayout.WidthConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Width,Factor=1}"
        RelativeLayout.HeightConstraint="{ConstraintExpression
        Type=RelativeToParent,Property=Height,Factor=1}">
        <!-- Your Grid Layout-->
    </Grid>
</RelativeLayout>
```

By default the background page color is white, so this will work, otherwise set the page's background color attribute to your desired one.